# LIST_NAME[-1] coming up with "]" python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am very new to python 3(and python in general), and I have decided to try to make a cypher and decypher in my own way as a personal project. The cypher works by generating a random number and multiplying the letters number value by it. It adds all of these multiplied values into a list and then adding the random number at the end.

Let's say that the list is [1976, 1995, 19]. The user would copy and paste this into the input and press enter

```py
dlist = list(input('Text to be Decyphered:'))
```

The function would then take the last value in the list and give the variable rnd the value. It would then delete this value from the list. After this it would divide the other values by rnd. The problem is that

```py
dlist[-1]
```

comes back with ']'

```py
import string
import random
from random import randrange
def cypher():
    rinput = input('Write Text to be Cyphered: ')
    rnd = randrange(0, 100)
    rinput = rinput.lower()
    output = []
    for character in rinput:
        number = ord(character) * rnd
        output.append(number)
    output.append(rnd)
    print(output)
def decypher():
    dlist = list(input('Text to be Decyphered:'))
    rnd = dlist[-2]
    rnd = int(rnd)
    dlist.pop()
    a = 1
    out = ""
    for number in dlist:
        vlc = int(dlist[a])
        vnum = vlc/rnd
        valf = chr(vnum)
        out + valf
        a=a+1
    print(out)
```

I think that the program is treating the list as a string because it is coming from an input() code.

Comment: Well, obviously. You answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `list` function, it converts the string to `['[', '1', '9', '7', '6', ',', ' ', '1', '9', '9', '5', ',', ' ', '1', '9', ']']`

Use instead:

```py
dlist = eval(input('Text to be Decyphered:'))
```

`eval` function will convert it to an actual list. You can cross check it:

```py
>>>print(type(eval('[1976, 1995, 19]')))
<class 'list'>
>>>print(eval('[1976, 1995, 19]'))
[1976, 1995, 19]
>>>for i in eval('[1976, 1995, 19]')
       print(i)
1976
1995
19
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems on your code:

1. randrange(0, 100)  -> if you get 0 then your result will all be 0 and won't work
2. Characters are Integers, Multiplication and division you will not always get an integer back so you man need to handle rounding
3. Your input to cypher is a String but the input of decypher is a list so you need to convert a list back to a string in a way you can parse it. maybe remove "[" and "]" the split the string

To convert a string to a list you can use something like

```
valToDecode = "[464, 404, 460, 464, 4]"
cleanedVal = valToDecode.strip("][").split(","))
```

Comment: note: you can use [`.strip("][")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) instead of the 2 replace calls

Comment: thanks, this probably would have been easier to parse with but just got it working thanks to @Sid.

Answer (score 0):

Try json on your input:

```
import json
data = json.loads(the_string)
```